# Mysterious crash report - looks like a CPU bug

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, crash-reports

A user sent me a crash dump of my program, and I cannot understand how what I'm seeing is possible. It looks like one of the registers just changed it's value, without any visible reason. I don't have any explanation except for a CPU bug, but I'm very skeptical about that. Perhaps you can spot what's going on here.

Here's the code disassembly, as seen when opening the crash report (clickable):

[image]

Here's, roughly, how the C code looks:

```
void **pp = *g_some_global;
if(!pp)
    return NULL;

int array_count = (int)pp[0];
void **array_ptr = (void **)pp[1];

for(i = 0; i < array_count; i++)
{
    LONG_PTR *contents = array_ptr[i];

    if(contents[4] == compare)
    {
        void **pp2 = (LONG_PTR *)contents[7]; // contents is different here! pp2 is NULL

        int array_count2 = (int)pp2[0]; // the CRASH!
        void **array_ptr2 = (void **)pp2[1];

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or bad RAM perhaps? That happens. CPU-bugs happen too, but probably not of this nature (they tend to be extremely obscure).

Comment: Is that C code reverse engineered from the disassembly, or something?  It looks awful.  There are all sorts of datatype assumptions.

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm working in the context of another process (DLL injection), accessing specific structure elements of the main process. This function should be called only from the UI thread, but even if not, it doesn't explain the behavior.

Comment: Perhaps operation of the pointer is  wrong.

Comment: It is not necessary for the same function to be called from multiple threads to have a conflict arising from a thread clash.  All that is necessary is for one thread to modify shared data that the other reads.  Without appropriate synchronization between threads it is very hard to reason about what behavior may be observed.

Comment: It's not clear from your code that what you think happened actually happened.  For example, you say that "contents" changed.  But what if `contents[7]` was already trashed by something else and was a NULL pointer?  In that case, RSI wasn't trashed, just your data structure was trashed.

Comment: @JS1 as I wrote in the first comment on the image, the check would not pass if `contents` (which is `RSI`) was of that value from the beginning. Unless, of course, the data changed while executing the couple of commands in between, but that's not likely, as the code is being executed from the UI thread, and nobody else should modify it. Also, it's very suspicious that `RSI` has the same value as `RBX`, and there's a command `mov rcx, rbx` just above the crash. I'm inclined to think [overclocking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/12/407562.aspx) might be the reason.

Comment: Ok, well your registers don't make sense at all.  For example, `RBX` was moved to `RCX` just a couple of instructions above your crash and yet `RBX` does not equal `RCX` in your register dump.  Does your program receive signals and have a signal handler?  What's interesting to me is that `RBX`, `RSI`, and `RDI` are non-volatile registers and all three look trashed.  This could be due to an interrupt/signal handler that does not clean up properly after itself.

Comment: Good catch. `RBX` should be zero (`xor ebx, ebx` is slightly above), so it looks like `RCX` has the correct value, as well as `RDX`. Seems like `RBX` was changed, just like `RSI`. And they both have the same value.

Comment: I don't know whether the program has a signal handler, or receives signals. Now when I look at the report again, I see that the exception is `0xC000041D`: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback. I don't know what it means, but I expected an access denied error. So it's not a `NULL` pointer exception, is it?

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's not a NULL pointer dereference after all.  Could you explain what your program does?  It is part of a device driver, for example?  Does it do any audio/video decoding?  It seems that some other part of your system is misbehaving.

Comment: The process is Windows Explorer. Googling for "explorer 0xC000041D" brings up a couple of results, so perhaps it's not related to my code. But it's weird that the crash points to a location in my library.